# SolidJS - How to update an prop referenced by component ID?

Tags: javascript, typescript, solid-js

Using SolidJS and Zod, how can I update a series of props (`props.error`) based upon the component ID matching the error path value? Currently, the prop will not update -- it remains blank.

Specifically, I want to pass the Zod error message to the InputCustom component to be displayed under each input form element.

**Form** *(Parent Component)*

```js
const handleSubmit = () => {
    try {
        // USING ZOD FOR FORM VALIDATION
        validateForm.parse(form)

    } catch (error: unknown) {
        const { errors } = error as ZodError
        errors.forEach(err => {
            console.log(err)

            // CURRENT LOGIC
            document.getElementById(err.path[0] as string)?.setAttribute('error', err.message)
        })

    }
}

return (
    <form>
        <InputCustom
            type='email'
            id='email'
            name='email'
            value={form.email}
            onInput={...}
            class={styles.email}
        >
            Email
        </InputCustom>

        ... // MORE INPUTS
    </form>
)
```

**InputCustom** *(Child Component)*

```js
const InputCustom: Component<ComponentProps<'input'> & { error?: string }> = props => {

    // DESTRUCTURING PROPS FOR CLEANLINESS.
    const { class: className, children, error, ...rest } = props

    return (
        <div class={`${styles.field} ${className ? className : ''}`}>
            <label for={props.id}>{children}</label>
            <input {...rest} class='sanded' />

            // DIRECTLY ACCESSING ERROR PROP FOR REACTIVE PROPERTIES
            <small textContent={props.error} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Example Error**

```json
{
    "code": "too_small",
    "minimum": 3,
    "type": "string",
    "inclusive": true,
    "exact": false,
    "message": "String must contain at least 3 character(s)",
    "path": [
        "username"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your error logic above is not how you update reactive DOM elements. Instead, you can use Solids `createStore` to create a reactive errors object, which allows you to update the object by a field id. I can put together a demo if needed. On the same note, you’ll pass down an `error={errors.email}` prop in addition to the other props.

Answer (score 0):

Solid needs to chain function calls to preserve reactivity from parent to child. When you destructure props you will be assigning values to static variables hence removing reactivity. So, in your child component you need to use property access like so: `pros.id`.

Only reactive values get updated, so you need to use a store or signal to store values that changes over time and pass them as props.

https://www.solidjs.com/tutorial/introduction_signals
https://www.solidjs.com/tutorial/props_defaults

Making sure you pass reactive values as props.

Once you done that you can use the destructuring utility from @solid-primitives library that relays values through proxy object as an alternative to property access:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@solid-primitives/destructure

Another alternative would be using a babel plugin that undoes the object destructuring during transpilation process. There is one experimental project but I could not remember the name at the moment.

Comment: Added logic to the original question. props.error is still not updating. Possibly need to update the prop in a different manner? Must I create a signal for each error prop??

Comment: Only reactive values get updated, so you need to use a store or signal to store values that changes over time.